# How to re-wrap a Linq Expression Tree

Tags: c#, linq, expression, metaprogramming, expression-trees

I have an `Expression<Func<Entity, string>>` that can be either a property or a nested property accessor

```
y => y.SearchColumn
```

or

```
y => y.SubItem.SubColumn
```

I am building up an expression tree dynamically and would like to get an InvokeExpression like this

```
x => x.SearchColumn.Contains("foo");
x => x.Sub.SearchColumn.Contains("foo");
```

I'm pretty sure I can unwrap the Expression body, then partially apply the x `ParameterExpression` to it but I can't figure out the magical incantations to make this happen

So I have something like

```
Expression<Func<Entity, string>> createContains(Expression<Func<Entity, string>> accessor) {
    var stringContains = typeof(String).GetMethod("Contains", new [] { typeof(String) });
    var pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "__x4326");
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<Entity, bool>>(
        Expression.Call(
            curryExpression(accessor.Body, pe),
            stringContains,
            Expression.Constant("foo")
        )
        , pe
    );              
}

    static Expression curryExpression(Expression from, ParameterExpression parameter) {
        // this doesn't handle the sub-property scenario
        return Expression.Property(parameter, ((MemberExpression) from).Member.Name);
        //I thought this would work but it does not
        //return Expression.Lambda<Func<Entity,string>>(from, parameter).Body;
    }
```

**Edit:**
[Here is the full thing I'm trying to do along with the error](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wo1Cfi)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do two things - first one you can use the same `accessor.Body`, but it will reference to incorrect Parameter, as you created a new one. Second one you need to write custom `ExpressionVisitor` that will replace all usage of original `y` `ParameterExpression` to a new created, so result expression will be compiled fine.

If you don't need to create new `ParameterExpression`, then you can just use the same `accessor.Body` and resent original `ParameterExpression` to a new tree.

So here is my test working copy with a new `ParameterExpression` - https://dotnetfiddle.net/uuPVAl

And the code  itself

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Expression<Func<Entity, string>> parent = (y) => y.SearchColumn;
        Expression<Func<Entity, string>> sub = (y) => y.Sub.SearchColumn;

        var result = Wrap(parent);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        result.Compile();

        result = Wrap(sub);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        result.Compile();

        result = Wrap<Entity>((y) => y.Sub.Sub.Sub.SearchColumn);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        result.Compile();

    }

    private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Wrap<T>(Expression<Func<T, string>> accessor)
    {
        var stringContains = typeof (String).GetMethod("Contains", new[] {typeof (String)});
        var pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof (T), "__x4326");
        var newBody = new ParameterReplacer(pe).Visit(accessor.Body);
        var call = Expression.Call(
            newBody,
            stringContains,
            Expression.Constant("foo")
            );
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(call, pe);
    }
}

public class ParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private ParameterExpression _target;

    public ParameterReplacer(ParameterExpression target)
    {
        _target = target;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        // here we are replacing original to a new one
        return _target;
    }
}

public class Entity
{
    public string SearchColumn { get; set; }

    public Entity Sub { get; set; }
}
```

PS: this example will work only if you have only one `ParameterExpression` in original query, otherwise visitor should differentiate them

**UPDATE**

Here is my working answer with your full example in update - https://dotnetfiddle.net/MXP7wE

Comment: Yes. The important thing to recognize is that expression trees are immutable, so in order to change some piece of an expression tree you need to create a complete copy of that expression tree with key portions of it changed, which is the purpose of an ExpressionVisitor.

Comment: Holy crap, awesome Sergey. Glad to know I was close :)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to a fix a couple of things:

- Return type of your method should be `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`.
- The 1st parameter to `Expression.Call()` should simply be `accessor.Body`.
- The `ParameterExpression` parameter to the `Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>()` method call should simply be set from the `accessor`'s parameter.

**Method:**

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>> CreateContains<T>(Expression<Func<T, string>> accessor)
{
    var stringContains = typeof(String).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(String) });
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
        Expression.Call(
            accessor.Body,
            stringContains,
            Expression.Constant("foo")
        )
        , accessor.Parameters[0]
    );
}
```

Comment: Did you take a look at my edit? [Here is the full thing I'm trying to do](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wo1Cfi)